# How to align the FormGroups with the FormElements in a SimpleForm [UI5, Fiori]

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

i do have the case in which i would like to have the `FormElements` be inline like [image: this] but also to have the group `title` in this case "First Group" and "Second Group" be aligned with the `FormElemens` block.

Code:

```
<form:SimpleForm
    title="Databinding basics: SimpleForm - Beispiel"
    layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" editable="true"
    columnsM="1" columnsL="1" columnsXL="3"
    labelSpanS="12" labelSpanM="4" labelSpanL="12"  labelSpanXL="2" 
    emptySpanS="0" emptySpanM="0" emptySpanL="0" emptySpanXL="0" singleContainerFullSize="false">
    <form:content>
      <core:Title text="First Group" emphasized="false" level="H4"/>
      <Label text="Enabled8"/>
        <Text text="Yes"/>
        <Label text="Enabled7"/>
        <Text text="Yes"/>
        <Label text="Enabled8"/>
        <Text text="Yes"/>
        <core:Title text="Second Group" emphasized="false" level="H4"/>
        <Label text="Enabled7"/>
        <Text text="Yes"/>
        <Label text="Enabled8"/>
        <Text text="Yes"/>
        <Label text="Enabled7"/>
        <Text text="Yes"/>
        <Label text="Enabled8"/>
        <Text text="Yes"/>
    </form:content>
</form:SimpleForm>
```

My attempt: Via adding `labelSpanXL="12"` and `emptySpan="0"` the alignment can be achieved but it puts the Label-Text vertically which i want to avoid.

**Question**: How can i achieve both for the `FormElements` to be inline as well as it be aligned with the group `Title`

Comment: Guess this is only possible with custom CSS. The labels have `text-align: end !important`. Changing that to `text-align: begin !important` should render it your way. But this is such a hack that you have to find out yourself how to implement it ;)

Comment: Is the SimpleForm rendered within an ObjectPageLayout? What are the parent controls of the form? And is your app supposed to follow the SAP Fiori design guidelines? Or is it a complete freestyle standalone app? And what is the target UI5 version?